Missing events when testing using envtest instead of external cluster
I'm using envtest to write & perform integration tests for a custom K8s controller built using controller-runtime.
The K8s controller essentially is watching endpointslices and a CRD. So when a service is created/modified or a deployment is created matching with a service, endpointslice events are expected to be generated and reconciled in the controller.
return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&v1discovery.EndpointSlice{}).
        Watches(&v1alpha1.CustomCRD{}, handler.EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc(mapFn)).
        Complete(s)

The endpointslice events are only being generated correctly when testing against a local K8s kind cluster.
os.Setenv("USE_EXISTING_CLUSTER", "true")

When using the test environment with its own k8s api server, etcd and certificate manager, the endpointslice events corresponding to service creation, deployment creation(with labels matching with that of the service) are not being generated.
The only endpointslice event generated while running envtest and configuring USE_EXISTING_CLUSTER to false is the default endpoint event for the K8s server.
&EndpointSlice{ObjectMeta:{kubernetes  default ....

I have tried these all but in vain when setting up the test suite.
corev1.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)

v1discovery.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)

appsv1.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)


What could possibly be the reason or what should I investigate next?
